# Selenium NoSuchElementException

Tags: java, spring, maven, jsp, selenium

I have this Spring - Maven - Tomcat setup for a webapplication.

I am testing with selenium and I can't locate an element by name, altough;

1) I'm waiting for the page to load,

2) the name is clearly set up in my .jsp view page.

Also, the main goal of the test is to enter a username and password, in the controller the page is redirected to the .jsp file beneath. Then the page gets time to load.

I have noticed that only with this error it kind of skips the waiting time.

Screenshot:
http://postimg.org/image/aka5az82l/

Error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element with name: newusername
```

JSP page:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Favorites: root</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>Add a User</p>

<spring:form action="/tdd/addUser" method="post" modelAttribute="user">

//Element name here
  <spring:input type="text" name="newusername" path="username"/>
  <spring:input type="password" name="newpassword" path="password"/>
  <input type="submit" value="ADD USER" name="Add user">

</spring:form>

</body>
</html>
```

Test Class:

```
 @Test
    public void testHomeScreenRoot() {
        WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
        driver.get("http://127.0.0.1:9999/tdd");
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("username"));
        element.sendKeys("root");
        element = driver.findElement(By.name("password"));
        element.sendKeys("rootpasswd");
            element.submit();
//Waiting here
            (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until((WebDriver d) -> d.getTitle().equals("Favorites: root"));

//Error here
        element = driver.findElement(By.name("newusername"));
        String tagName = element.getTagName();
        assertEquals("input", tagName);

        element = driver.findElement(By.name("newpassword"));
        tagName = element.getTagName();
        assertEquals("input", tagName);

        element = driver.findElement(By.name("Add user"));
        tagName = element.getTagName();
        assertEquals("input", tagName);

        String type = element.getAttribute("type");
        assertEquals("submit", type);
    }
```

Comment: Can you verify that the field is actually called `newusername` by loading the page in a browser and inspecting it using dev console?

Comment: It isn't, but why? @GergelyBacso

[link](http://postimg.org/image/yn0o9sge3/)

Comment: Selenium only gets to meet your final HTML content, does not see the Spring code you wrote. If the HTML field called `username` (coming from the `path` variable I guess), then you need to give *that* to Selenium, not `newusername`.

Comment: You are right, but the exercise is to make the test pass without changing anything to it, I could change the `path` to `newusername` but then I get an error on that also `Invalid property "newusername" of bean class` so I need to change the `User` class. But the test is intended to work like that right?

Comment: These three variables are to be in sync: your `path` variable + the string you use for Selenium + the bean field in the app. Decide which one of these you are allowed to overwrite? A logical thing would be to adjust the test to the prod code, but if you got this as an assignment, you may operate under different rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the fact that I can't change the test class (it was an assignment on test driven development).

I have changed the input field from Spring inputs to standard HTML inputs.
This solution works and the new user is stored.

I acknowledge the fact that it is an easier and cleaner way to just change the test.

Anyway, here is the .jsp code:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Favorites: root</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>Add a User</p>
<spring:form action="/tdd/addUser" method="post" modelAttribute="user">

//changed to basic html inputfields

  <input name="newusername" type="text" />
  <input name="newpassword" type="password" />
  <input type="submit" value="ADD USER" name="Add user">

</spring:form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Anyone than can explain the difference? My controller picks up the fields anyway..

Answer (score 2):

This might be flexible enough to help reveal the issue, since it will work for name `username` as well as `newusername`:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//input[contains(@name, 'username')]");
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem is caused by the fact, that in this example the `path` variable controls the final name of the HTML tag, so based on this line:

```
<spring:input type="text" name="newusername" path="username"/>
```

the following Selenium expression:

```
element = driver.findElement(By.name("newusername"));
```

should be changed to:

```
element = driver.findElement(By.name("username"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the selenium is losting the reference because the path, I think that if you put an Id in your element and change the code to find by Id, this error will not occurs more..